# Force the roll of LoggerAppenderRollingFile

Tags: php, web-applications, logging, log4php

I am using log4php to log some activities in my application.

I want the log file will be rolled once every X time and not only once a day / when it reach to a certain size.

Is there a way of doing that?

Is there a way to force the log to roll at certain time?

If not, some one know another good logger (open source preferred) I can use.

Answer (score 2):

By using the `LoggerAppenderDailyFile`, you can specify a `datePattern`, which accepts any parameter that is valid for the `date()` function as well. Whenever the date pattern changes, you'll get a new file created.

Including seconds in the pattern will create a new logfile every second (but only if log output is created).

There is also the option of dynamically change the configuration. You can pass a php array to the `Logger::configure()` call and setup the filename inside behaving like you want.